# Node Not Found In AWS VPC For Create RabbitMQ cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-vpc

try to configure RabbitMQ cluster on AWS VPC

i exchange the cookies from master node to second node

and do the following step

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server stop
sudo rabbitmqctl stop_app
sudo rabbitmqctl reset
sudo rabbitmqctl cluster rabbit@ip-10-0-2-215
```

gives an error

Clustering node 'rabbit@ip-10-0-2-108' with ['rabbit@ip-10-0-2-215'] ...
Error: {no_running_cluster_nodes,['rabbit@ip-10-0-2-215'],                             ['rabbit@ip-10-0-2-215']}

All port in firewall configuration

able to ping between that two Instance

i am using RabbitMQ -v 2.8.2

note: same process done out side AWS VPC and it's work so what possible problem with VPC

Comment: this problem solve there are problem in AWS VPC to resolve DNS name of the rabbit node for resolving dns i add master RabbitMQ node name entry in host file and it working thanks.

Answer (score 2):

RabbitMQ doesn't DNS unfortunately (because Erlang has poor support for cluster nodes identified by they FQDNs).

You need to be sure that each RabbitMQ node can connect to the other.  Try checking the status of one node from the other.  Use something like:

```
rabbitmqctl -n rabbit@ip-10-0-2-215 status
```

If that doesn't work, you'll need to check that both nodes have the same [Erlang cookie](http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#setup).  If it still doesn't work after that, you'll need to add the hostnames to your `/etc/hosts` files on the two instances.

If you still have issues, send a message to the [RabbitMQ Discuss](https://lists.rabbitmq.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rabbitmq-discuss) mailing list.  The developers answer all the questions there, and there are other people who've managed to set up RabbitMQ clusters on AWS.